# Java: Comparing Cells in an Array

Tags: java

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read my question,

I have a matrix of randomly generated boolean values, what I want to do is compare each individual cell of the matrix to its surroundings, by surroundings I mean the cells to the immediate left, right, top, bottom, and all 4 diagonals. If a surrounding cell is true I need it to return a "1", if false, a "0", so that I may add the number of true and false cells surrounding an individual cell, so an output would be something like "1 + 1 + 1 + 0 etc". Im very sorry if I have explained this poorly, if more information in needed please let me know.

Comment: When coding my own version of Minesweeper, I believe I just resorted to nested for-loops to check the surrounding cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to implement this is to nest two `for` loops, one for x and one for y, with an array of the values [-1, 0, 1]. Make sure to account for boundaries of the matrix, and don't add the value of the current cell.

One note: this would be a good place to split your code into two methods, one doing the looping and calling the other with coordinates, while the other performs edge-case checking and returns the result.

Answer (score 3):

You're applying a [two-dimensional convolution](http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution.html#convolution_2d) on a matrix, with a kernel of size 3 that is:

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

(If you meant to include the current cell in the sum, the middle should be 1 instead of 0).

You can either hard-code the kernel or, for nicer and more general code, accept a 3-by-3 kernel as input. If you don't need a general solution you can just follow syrion's advice. To convert the booleans to 1's and 0's you can do something like: `cellNum = cellValue ? 1 : 0`, for example.